# How to combine query in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have draws on my site, in order to take part in the draw, you need to do a certain action per day. And there is a code that checks it all:

```
    $date = Carbon::today();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=', $date)->get();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets_1x1')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=', $date)->get();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets_low')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=',$date)->get();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets_duel')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=', $date)->get();

if ($sta == NULL) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Error']);
            }
```

This code checks if there is a user record in 4 possible tables. I made an entry in the table `ets_1x1`, but still I can’t take part, because the error seemed to not find me in the database. I removed all the tables and left only `ets_1x1` and I was accepted into the drawing.

As I understand it, the value is taken from the last request. How can I combine a query into 1 and do a check on these 4 tables?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create relations on user model and do something like this

```
$user=User::with(['ets','ets_1x1','ets_low','ets_duel'])->find($this->user->id);
```